# Chained Method in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

Please explain the last angle brackets in the code:

```
function gotoPage(newPage) { 
    nextPage = newPage.options[newPage.selectedIndex].value {    
        document.location.href = nextPage 
    }
}
```

{ document.location.href = nextPage } is obviously assigning nextPage to document.location.href, but it is chained (method?) to nextPage = newPage.options[newPage.selectedIndex].value?

Comment: Hi. If you want us to help you, you need to do something first, not just post us your homework

Comment: @Mekap: There's a very clear attempt above to understand the code, this is not a homework dump.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I actually think that he just posted the code of the assignement, and then some trivial questions just to make it look like a "very clear attempt."

Comment: @Mekap: I really don't think so, the questions show too much effort for the kind of person who would do that. But it's always possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Line 1: Is it declaring the function "gotoPage" with "newPage" as an attribute or a value?

It's declaring a `gotoPage` function with a `newpage` **argument**.

> Line 3: It is assigning the object "nextPage" with (can anyone explain what " nextPage = newPage.options[newPage.selectedIndex]. value" is?

`nextPage` is apparently a variable declared outside the `gotoPage` function. (Either that, or the code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).) Yes, the code is assigning a new value to it.

The value it's assigning comes from `newPage.options[newPage.selectedIndex].value`, like this:

- `newPage.options` gets the `options` property value from the `newPage` object, which is apparently an HTML `select` element, and so that `options` property will hold an array-like list of the select options.
- `[newPage.selectedIndex]` gets the `newPage.selectedIndex` number and then looks up the entry in the list at that position, which will be an `option` object.
- `.value` gets the `value` property of that option. (The option's value.)

So we end up with `nextPage` being the `value` of the selected option in the `newPage` select box, which is a string.

> Line 4: "document.location.href" - I know that in javascript, "location." is an object and ".href" is a property. But what is "document."? Another object?

Yes, it's the object that represents the HTML document in the browser window.

> Line 4: What is "document.location.href = nextPage" doing?

If that works, it's a bit of a new one to me. :-) But if it does, I'm guessing it takes the browser to the URL in `nextPage`. Normally that would be written as simply `location = nextPage` or `location.href = nextPage`, which is using the `location` on `window` rather than `document` (they both have them), but browsers probably allow you to navigate by assigning to either of them.

Comment: Thank you so T.J for your reply. It's very helpful.